# Parallel execution issue

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I need a little education here with regards to the execution of parallel tasks.

I have created a small fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/JO2a4m

What I am trying to do send a few accounts to process in batches to another method and creating a unit of work (task) for each batch but when I execute the tasks, it only executes the last task which was added. This is something I am trying to break my head around.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var accounts = GenerateAccount();
        var accountsProcess = new List<Account>();
        var taskList = new List<Task>();
        var batch = 4;
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var account in accounts)
        {
            if (count == batch)
            {
                taskList.Add(new Task(() => ProcessAccount(accountsProcess)));
                count = 0;
                accountsProcess.Clear();
            }

            count++;
            accountsProcess.Add(account);
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(taskList, t =>
        {
            t.Start();
        }

        );
        Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
        if (accountsProcess.Count > 0)
            ProcessAccount(accountsProcess);
    }

    public static List<Account> GenerateAccount()
    {
        var accounts = new List<Account>();
        var first = "First";
        var second = "Second";
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            var account = new Account();
            account.first = first + i;
            account.second = second + i;
            accounts.Add(account);
        }

        return accounts;
    }

    public static void ProcessAccount(List<Account> accounts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(accounts.Count);
        foreach (var account in accounts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(account.first + account.second);
        }
    }
}

public class Account
{
    public string first;
    public string second;
}
```

Comment: Don't mix TPL `Parallel.xxxx` with `Task`. 1) it doesn't play nice with I/O 2) `Parallel.ForEach` is already spinning up a CPU-bound thread, why create/fetch another one from the thread pool via `Task`?

Comment: Also, it is discouraged to use the Task constructors. Tasks should be created and started with Task.Run. However, like MickyD said there is no benefit in using tasks here.

Comment: Yep. Thanks for info. I have removed and changed it from my original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (var account in accounts)
{
    if (count == batch)
    {
        taskList.Add(new Task(() => ProcessAccount(accountsProcess)));
        count = 0;
        accountsProcess.Clear();
    }

    count++;
    accountsProcess.Add(account);
}
```

The issue is that all of the `Task`s are sharing the same `List<Account>` object.

I would suggest changing the code to:

```
foreach (var account in accounts)
{
    if (count == batch)
    {
        var bob = accountsProcess;
        taskList.Add(new Task(() => ProcessAccount(bob)));
        count = 0;
        accountsProcess = new List<Account>();
    }

    count++;
    accountsProcess.Add(account);
}
```

By using `bob` and assigning a new `List` to `accountsProcess` we ensure each `Task` gets its own `List` - rather than sharing a single `List`.

*Also, consider using [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/)'s `Batch` rather than rolling your own.*